# Catalogue for online-shop alternative solutions

Tags: html, css

I usually make catalogue for online-shop like this

```
<div class="catalogue">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</div><!-- .catalogue -->


.catalogue {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
.catalogue ul {
    margin: -18px 0 40px -16px;
    word-spacing: -1em;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.catalogue li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 226px;
    margin: 22px 0 0 16px;
    font: normal 15px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I need all these "-spacing" and etc to remove the 3 px padding in browsers.

And for Safari 5.1.7 on Windows I have to add this line

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {.catalogue ul {display: table; /* Safari only */}}
```

You can take a look at the working example here http://jsfiddle.net/N4gKg/7/

I wonder if there are more effective solutions.

Comment: The problem is what exactly?

Comment: There is no problem. I am just looking for some alternative solutions.

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with the solution you have, then this question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: Ok, then it should be deleted I think.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post. This will help you
http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: @640miles whats the problem with this?

Comment: That's not my minus, if you were asking about this. But in general the link you gave does not correspond with the topic. In every catalogue item is usually some content like image, description, link.

Comment: I have posted that link so that you will get some idea from that. Any way its not